# Working backwards from known email address with encryption

Tags: sql, encryption

Background: I'm the data analyst for a website that drives a reasonable amount of traffic. The goal of the site is to get people to sign up. Each month we report on our signups by source - what marketing campaign did they come in on. So when a person signs up their referrer info is grabbed and placed into the database.

Back in April a flaw in our website led to us losing all of this data, though we still captured the email addresses we did not know where they came from.

We use Google Analytics on the website. When someone signs up their encrypted email address is shown as a page view within the console. I can see all of the associated referring information against the encrypted email addresses.

I've never worked with encryption before but remember from a webdev class I took last year the teacher showing an example of encrypting a field in phpMyAdmin.

I now wonder if it's possible to apply encryption to the known email addresses, then do a join on the encryped addresses from Google Analytics, thus obtaining the associated referring info.

Has anyone ever done this? Is there a way to tell what encryption format to use? I am straying way out of my realm of knowledge and I know that this question is probably too vague for a typical SO question but I'm seeking a pointer. Is what I'm doing possible? Is there a "right way" to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats a tough situation.  There are thousands of different encryption schemes and after doing some quick googling I don't think google wants to give away their encryption schemes / methods to the general public.   Google may encrypt these email addresses, for example, by using the current time and, thus, you would be unable to recreate the same encrypted email for the same email.  Sorry buddy.

Comment: I thought it might be harder than it sounds. Though I don;t think the actual encryption is done by Google Analytics, our developers applied the encryption to comply with Google's "No personally identifiable info should be visible within Google Analytics". I'm hoping that if this is the case then our devs would know how to work backwards, still waiting to hear from them. My hope was that, since I'm working backwards from a known email address, rather than trying to find an unknown email address, that it may be possible